# TSQL - Select rows where column value has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Rep table with the following fields:

[image]

There can be changes to the RepNbr.  I need to write a query that shows what the repnbr was for each effectivedate.  What the repnbr was prior and then when there's a change.  So, I'm trying to pull the repnbr of M258 on 10/21 (what the repnbr was prior), the repnbr of DM25 on 6/3/16 and what the repnbr of M258 was on 6/8/16.

I tried the following query:  This query only pulls the effectivedate of 6/3 and 6/8 and doesn't look back to what the repnbr was previously.

```
    ;with t1 as
(
select 
     acctnbr, 
     repnbr, 
     effectivedate,
     rn = row_number() over (partition by repnbr order by acctnbr)
from 
     reptable
where 
     acctnbr = '123'
)
select 
     *
from 
     t1
where  
     rn = '1'
order by 
     effectivedate
```

Results:

[image]

My output should look like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with my query?
Thanks,

Comment: how should the output look like?

Comment: `I'm trying to pull the repnbr of M258 on 10/21` -- I don't find any reference of this in your code

Comment: all you have done is exclude one row of data... and you are going to want to partition by Acct, EffectiveDate so you get one record for each account for each effective date. Since your rows are unique anyway, all of this seems trivial. Perhaps your real dataset would show a better example.

Comment: you sure your output would look like that?  EffectiveDate is not in order in your list.  So if you are looking for changes based on effective date your output would not look like that see my answer for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `LAG()` and or `LEAD()` functions for SQL 2012+

```
DECLARE @Rep AS TABLE (Acct INt, RepNbr CHAR(4), EffectiveDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Rep VALUES
(123,'M258','2015-10-15')
,(123,'M258','2015-10-21')
,(123,'DM25','2015-06-03')
,(123,'M258','2015-06-08')

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
       ,LAG(RepNbr) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as PrevRepNbr
    FROM
       @Rep
)

SELECT Acct, RepNbr, EffectiveDate
FROM
    cte 
WHERE
    PrevRepNbr IS NULL
    OR PrevRepNbr <> RepNbr
```

Note though that your example isn't in order of Effective Date so your results will not be as you described.  Because 10-21 is after 6-3...

```
Acct    RepNbr  EffectiveDate
123     DM25    2015-06-03 00:00:00.000
123     M258    2015-06-08 00:00:00.000
123     M258    2015-10-15 00:00:00.000
123     M258    2015-10-21 00:00:00.000
```

So that would mean that the RepNbr only changes on 6/8 from DM25 to M258

If you change your example table to:

```
DECLARE @Rep AS TABLE (Acct INt, RepNbr CHAR(4), EffectiveDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Rep VALUES
(123,'M258','2015-06-03')
,(123,'M258','2015-06-08')
,(123,'DM25','2015-10-15')
,(123,'M258','2015-10-21')
```

Then it woudl start with M258 on 6/3 change to DM25 on 10/15 and then change back to M258 on 10/21.

If you don't want to see the original/starting value just remove the `WHERE PrevRepNbr IS NULL`

Edit without @Rep:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       Acct
       ,RepNbr
       ,EffectiveDate
       ,LAG(RepNbr) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY EffectiveDate) as PrevRepNbr
    FROM
       TableName
)

SELECT Acct, RepNbr, EffectiveDate
FROM
    cte 
WHERE
    PrevRepNbr IS NULL
    OR PrevRepNbr <> RepNbr
```

Comment: This will work except I have 600,000+ accounts to do an Insert Into @Rep.  Is there a way to pull the data without doing INSERT INTO?  I'm only showing one example.

Comment: yeah just replace FROM @Rep with FROM Tablename of your original table and not use the table variable at all

Comment: @BIGuy if my answer worked for you please consider accepting it so others know you got what you needed and reputation points are assigned.  thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I have SQL Server2012, but the LAG function doesn't work.     Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name. - Wierd.

Comment: @BIGuy what's the databse compatibility level for the database you are querying?  Perhaps it is pre 2012?  did the DB exist on a past version of SQL prior to being migrated to a 2012+ server? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Older Sql sever versions grouping

```
DECLARE @Rep AS TABLE (Acctnbr int, RepNbr CHAR(4), EffectiveDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Rep VALUES
(123,'M258','2015-10-15')
,(123,'M258','2015-10-21')
,(123,'DM25','2015-06-08')
,(123,'M258','2015-06-03');

WITH cte AS (
  select *, 
   grp = row_number() over(partition by acctnbr order by effectivedate)
   - row_number() over(partition  by acctnbr, RepNbr  order by effectivedate)
     from @rep
)
SELECT acctnbr, RepNbr, max(effectivedate) effectivedate
from cte
group by acctnbr, RepNbr, grp
order by acctnbr, max(effectivedate) desc;
```

Comment: a change typically becomes effective on a minimum EffectiveDate not maximum but I agree the OP makes it seem different due to expected results and example data being out of order.

Comment: @matt, Sure OP can sort it out and choose min /max as needed. Thanks for hint anyway.